# prepare function not called - swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I have a collection view. each item should pass data to second view, in other world I want to pass current view to second view by `navigationController`.

```
class GroupsViewController: UIViewController ,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

....
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events

    var group = self.items[indexPath.item]

    var cat_title = group.cat_title

    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GroupSubOneTableViewController") as UIViewController, animated: true)

}

....

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        print("ooopps")
        if (segue.identifier == "GroupSubOneTableViewController") {
            let navController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let detailController = navController.topViewController as! GroupSubOneTableViewController
            //detailController.currentId = nextId!

            print("selected GroupSubOneTableViewController")
        }
    }
```

but in console log doesn't show anything!

Comment: `prepare` is only called when you perform a segue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing here two thing `perfomSegue` and `pushViewController`. [`perform​Segue(with​Identifier:​sender:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue)
 is called when you perform a segue using `performSegue`. So create one segue from your `SourceVC` to `DestinationVC`.

If you want to go with `pushViewController` then simply type cast `UIViewController` to your `ViewController` pass the data.

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GroupSubOneTableViewController") as! GroupSubOneTableViewController
//pass vaue
vc.passStr = "Hello"
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not called because `pushViewController` doesn't perform a segue.

You need to call `performSegue(withIdentifier: "GroupSubOneTableViewController", sender: self)` instead of `pushViewController`.

Of course, you'll also need to set this up in your storyboard.